# Linux replace space to dot for each row only

Tags: linux, shell-script

I am writing a shellscript to get the query output and replace space to dot for each row

```
sql_query="SHOW STATS_HEALTHY WHERE Healthy < 90;"
echo "Running the SQL query..."
query_result=$(eval "$mysql_cmd")
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "SQL query executed successfully. Output:"
  selected_columns=$(echo "$query_result" | cut -f 1,2)
  echo "Selected columns: $selected_columns"

  #Tried below 2 is not expected output 
  echo $selected_columns | tr ' ' '.'
  echo $selected_columns | sed 's/ /./g'
```

**Current Output:**

[image]

**Tried below 3 is not expected output**

```
 echo $selected_columns | tr ' ' '.'
 echo $selected_columns | sed 's/ /./g'
 echo $selected_columns | sed 's/\s/./g'
```

[image]

**Expected:**
Execute the query output and replace space to dot for each row.

**Expected Output**

```
loxxx.Vxxxx
loxxx.Vxxxx
loxxx.Gxxxx
loxxx.Gxxxx
loxxx.Gxxxx
```

**Solution:**

```
printf '%s\n' "$selected_columns" | sed 's/\s/./g'
```

[image]

Comment: Try this : `sed 's/ /\./g'`

Comment: `#Tried below 2 is not expected output`, so what did happen instead?

Comment: @MarcusMüller Ohhh, indeed, I tried with and without escape, same - good - results. I need a coffee :).

Comment: Oh, I know. The columns are tab separated.

Comment: Sorry, try this then `sed 's/\s/./g'`

Comment: hi @MarcusMüller, the output was like `loxxxx.Vxxxx.loxxxx.Gxxxxx.loxxxx.Gxxxxx` and so on.

Comment: hi @K-attila- tried your suggestion the output `loxxxx.Vxxxx.loxxxx.Gxxxxx.loxxxx.Gxxxxx`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`echo $selected_columns` replaces newlines by spaces, making it all one line.

Quoting the variable will also add an extra newline of its own, and using `echo -n` is deprecated because echo may be a built-in (varies between shells) or /bin/echo.

Use `printf '%s\n' "$selected_columns"`

The handling of newlines here is arguable. Each `$( ... )` removes trailing newlines, so I think `printf` need to explicitly add one. Verify your output carefully (`od -t acx1` never lies to you).

Comment: Thank you @Paul_Pedant, works expected result. 

`printf '%s\n' "$selected_columns" | sed 's/\s/./g'`